Hiding empty cells in Excel chart
I would like to set up a graphic that is fixed to a cell range. The values there change depending on the data input. If a cell is empty, the axis labelling is still displayed in the graphic. How can I prevent this and still not adjust my data range manually every time?
I have tried the method to indicate an error if the field is empty. The axis values are still displayed.

Can you provide more information about your problem? What chart type are you using? Are the blank cells in the middle of the dataset, missing just a value, or is the range dynamic and therefore the chart selection will have extra rows that aren't used?

The range dynamic and therefore the chart selection have extra rows at the end that aren't used. The chart is currently a bar chart.

I'm going to assume your data is starts at A2 into column B for the values. What you want to do is create named ranges in the Name Manager, which can be found in the Formulas tab of the ribbon, by hitting Define Name. I'm also going to assume the max length of your table is 100. If you need more or less adjust accordingly. Both data points will need to be filled in to appear in the chart.
Assuming your labels are in Col A, =$A$2:Index($A$2:$A$100,count($A$2:$A$100)) then name this as _Labels
Then for the values (Col B), put =$B$2:Index($B$2:$B$100,count($B$2:$B$100)) then name this as _Values
Then under "Select Data" of your chart, in the legend series add the values like so, replacing the sheet name with what is relevant for you.

Then, on the horizontal category, hit "Edit", and add the _Labels.

You'll notice I have Book1, that's just because I made it a workbook wide name, but you can make these sheet specific and if you do just make sure they're labelled accordingly. This will hide blanks from your bar graph.

Hi Mark, thanks for helping me! So I put your formula for the values in cell D2 and named this cell values. When I add this to my chart, only the first cells in the bar chart (C2 and D2) that I named are shown.

It doesn't sound like you followed the process. We aren't naming the cells. We're creating a name in the name manager and putting the formula in there. I added some details and formatting to make this step more obvious.


Go to the Formulas tab and select Name Manager.
Click New to create a new named range.
For the categories:
Name: DynamicCategories
Refers to: =OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2, 0, 0, COUNTA(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$100), 1)
For the values:
Name: DynamicValues
Refers to: =OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$2, 0, 0, COUNTA(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$100), 1)

Create the Chart:

Select an empty cell where you want to insert your chart.
Go to the Insert tab and select the type of chart you want to create (e.g., Line Chart, Column Chart).
Once the chart is inserted, right-click on it and select Select Data.
In the Select Data Source window, click on Add to add a new data series.
For the series name, you can leave it blank or refer to a cell.
For the Series values, enter the formula: =Sheet1!DynamicValues
Then, click on the Edit button for the Horizontal (Category) Axis Labels.Enter the formula: =Sheet1!DynamicCategories


This looks like an ChatGPT answer which is against SO rules ...
